# Разметка ListView. Выровнять три TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, android-layout, разметка

Необходимо повторить данный список. Это список ближайших рейсов на остановке (картинка с сайта).

[image: список ближайших остановок]

Опыт на андройде у меня дико мал, однако стараюсь в спешке быстро освоить. В общем я сделал это через адаптер и listwiew, однако понятие не имею как выровнять так идеально по заголовку или вообще сделать заголовок. Я не требую готовое решение, но хотя бы ссылку на статью или что-то более конкретное. Ниже предоставлю свою разметку и изображение как это выглядит сейчас.

Ниже будет разметка активити выводящее listview

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv_name_stops"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Остановка"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewNearestRoutes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name_stops">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка самого listview. Я не знал что нужно прислать, потому закинул сразу всё.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvNumRoute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bus"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:text="900"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeRoute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/invstops"
            android:text="в 13:46"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tvDirectionRoute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ТРЦ КомсоМОЛЛ (Б)"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ниже, как и писал ранее, изображение как моя кривая разметка выглядит в итоге.

[image: Список остановок на моём приложении]

Я не часто пишу на форумах... Если я что-то написал не так, то прошу прощения и буду признателен за наставления.

Comment: [попробуйте это](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-ListView-Header.htm)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)
Ответил не скоро, так как заморозили проект временно.

Answer (score 0):

возможно я сейчас Вас отправлю по неверному пути, но я когда-то делал вот так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llLoad"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

    </TextView>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCostDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

    </TextView>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

    </TextView>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPercent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

    </TextView>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: результат]